# Deleting pictures from slides since last save

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

Please bear with me as I explain, hopefully succinctly, my question. I have a user form that, among other things, allows the user to insert a picture into a subset of sets in the project [i.e., slides 3-29 and 30-54]. I want to create a "Clear" subroutine that will, among other things, remove any inserted pictures from the slides subsequent to the last SAVE. My thinking is with each "insert" picture procedure, a public 2 dimension variable is created which contains the slide number and shape.ID pair. The clear routine will simply look through these variables, go to each slide and delete the picture. (Upon each SAVE these variables get erased.

Is my logic sound? Should I be going down a different route? Having never worked with multi-dimensional variables, how do I specify or read each variable pair's values to parse through them?

Comment: Your logic sounds good.  It is often hard to tell exactly what you'll run into until you do it.  I'd say give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

As you add each image get a reference to its shape and add a tag to it, something like (assuming a reference to the new picture in oSh):

oSh.Tags.Add "Added", dTime
' where dTime is a variable that's set to the previous save date
' You can do ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "LastSave", whatever to record that

To remove the shapes as desired, cycle through each shape on each slide and look at

oSh.Tags("Added") to return the dTime value you tagged with when the presentation was added.  When you fine one that matches your criteria, delete it.

Be sure to walk backwards through the shapes on each slide, else you'll get odd results.

Before this'll work, you'll need to figure out how to record the last save date (and time?).  Do you have that worked out?